# 500 internal server error at GetResponse()

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, web-services, web-applications

I have a heavy traffic aspx page calling a web service upon every user`s request as follows.

```
string uri = "Path.asmx";
string soap = "soap xml string";

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "\"http://xxxxxx"");
request.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
request.Accept = "text/xml";
request.Method = "POST";

using (Stream stm = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    using (StreamWriter stmw = new StreamWriter(stm))
    {
        stmw.Write(soap);
    }
}
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
response.close();
```

Everything is working fine but sometimes I am getting the following error.

**The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()**

Does anybody have any idea about this error or can anybody tell me if I am doing wrong.

Comment: If it works sometimes and not others, you need to post the soap xml of a failure.  Something is wrong there, not in the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I get rid of internal server error message with the following code. Not sure if there is another way to achieve it.

```
string uri = "Path.asmx";
string soap = "soap xml string";

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "\"http://xxxxxx"");
request.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
request.Accept = "text/xml";
request.Method = "POST";

using (Stream stm = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    using (StreamWriter stmw = new StreamWriter(stm))
    {
        stmw.Write(soap);
    }
}

using (WebResponse webResponse = request.GetResponse())
{
}
```

Comment: using is try-finally {dispose}. Good way to get rid of exception is to ignore it with try-catch. Ha-ha

Answer (score 57):

For me this error occurred because I had 2 web API actions that had the exact same signatures and both had the same verbs, `HttpPost`, what I did was change one of the verbs (the one used for updating) to PUT and the error was removed. The following in my catch statement helped in getting to the root of the problem:

```
catch (WebException webex)
{
                WebResponse errResp = webex.Response;
                using (Stream respStream = errResp.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(respStream);
                    string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
}
```

Comment: This is not well documented and it takes me forever to find it. Thank you for the example!

Comment: Found this very helpful.

Consider changing to the following if you intend to keep it or need to read the output from teamcity or a CI box.

catch (WebException webException)
{
    WebResponse webResponse = webException.Response;

    using (Stream responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
    {
        if (responseStream == null)
        {
            throw;
        }

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
        String text = reader.ReadToEnd();

        throw new WebException(text, webException);
    }
}

Comment: Thanks! much appreciated

Comment: that's it,you rock.

Comment: It did tell me which part is exception. Thanks for pointing it out too..

Answer (score 22):

From that error, I would say that your code is fine, at least the part that calls the webservice. The error seems to be in the actual web service.

To get the error from the web server, add a try catch and catch a WebException. A WebException has a property called Response which is a HttpResponse. you can then log anything that is returned, and upload you code. Check back later in the logs and see what is actually being returned.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried to specify UserAgent for your request? For example:

```
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)";
```

Comment: Missing UserAgent causes a lot of websites with dynamic content to throw an error. Good advice when writing a scraper, but shouldn't be needed with SOAP or REST apis.

Answer (score 0):

looking at your error message first of all I would suggest you to recompile your whole application, make sure all the required dlls are there in bin folder when you recompile it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case my request object inherited from base object. Without knowingly I added a property with int? in my request object and my base object also has same property ( same name ) with int datatype. I noticed this and deleted the property which I added in request object and after that it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

For me the error was misleading. I discovered the true error by testing the errant web service with SoapUI.

Comment: ...and found that is was..?

Comment: SteveCav: the true error could be almost anything: the point is that testing with SoapUI yielded the REAL error message, and not the meaningless "internal server error".

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just remove the `SoapAction` instruction from the `HttpWebRequest` object. So, I don't define `.Headers.Add("SOAPAction","someurl")` in `HttpWebRequest` definitions and my code works fine.

`ResultXML` is an `XDocument`.
`ResultString` is a string.

```
try
{
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);
    //req.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "http://tempuri.org/IWebService/GetMessage");
    req.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
    req.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
    req.Accept = "text/xml";
    req.KeepAlive = true;
    req.Method = "POST";        

    using (Stream stm = req.GetRequestStream())
    {
        using (StreamWriter stmw = new StreamWriter(stm))
            stmw.Write(soapStr);
    }
    using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
    {
        string result = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
        ResultXML = XDocument.Parse(result);
        ResultString = result;      
    }
}
```