# POST with WebRequest problem

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, post

This is the POST message to service of Google Chrome:
[image: This is the POST message to service of Google Chrome:]
I want post this POST message from C#:

```
System.Net.WebRequest req = 
System.Net.WebRequest.Create(@"http://www.ччч.ru/SystemService.asmx/VotingFoPhoto");
req.Method = "POST";
req.Timeout = 12000;
req.ContentType = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";

byte[] sentData = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetBytes("photoId=E6A0327A&concursId=3");
req.ContentLength = sentData.Length;
System.IO.Stream sendStream = req.GetRequestStream();
sendStream.Write(sentData, 0, sentData.Length);
sendStream.Close();

req.GetResponse();
```

When i run this code, i get 500 server error. Help me please.

Comment: The link http://www.ччч.ru/SystemService.asmx/VotingFoPhoto is not valid

Comment: It is the most common http error message check this and see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098945/500-internal-server-error-at-getresponse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have told the server your `content-type` is `application/json`. But you have provided content in `application/x-www-urlencoded` format.

Try providing JSON format:

```
byte[] sentData = 
  Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetBytes("{'photoId':'E6A0327A';'concursId':3}");
```

Alternatively try changing the content-type header.