# WebException response didn't return the full response

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, webclient, windows-authentication

I am using WebClient in my Web API service (Windows Autheticated) to make a HTTP call to our Corporate directory (Windows Autheticated) to get profile for a user. Please see below.

```
public string DownloadPage(string ntid)
    {
        var result = "";

        try
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient() {UseDefaultCredentials = true})
            {
                using (var stream = client.OpenRead($"{url}{urlParameter}{ntid}"))
                {
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                    {
                        result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error(ex); 
        }

        log.Info(result);
        return result;
    }
```

The code works perfect locally and in our testing environment, but returned "500 internal server error" when I deployed it to Produciton environment. I resolved the 500 error based on the solution from [500 internal server error at GetResponse()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098945/500-internal-server-error-at-getresponse). Please see codes below. However, I found that only part of html got returned. Is there anything like body length or max return size I need to set from code or IIS?

```
 public string DownloadPage(string ntid)
    {
        var result = "";

        try
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient() {UseDefaultCredentials = true})
            {
                using (var stream = client.OpenRead($"{url}{urlParameter}{ntid}"))
                {
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                    {
                        result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (WebException webex)
        {
            //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098945/500-internal-server-error-at-getresponse
            var errResp = webex.Response;
            using (var stream = errResp.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error(ex); 
        }

        log.Info(result);
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us the response header which shows the full content-length? How much of the content is returned? How large is the HTML response?

Comment: Can you capture the traffic with [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) to see the real response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have access to active directory that's why code works on local but on IIS the application pool is running from ApplicationPoolIdentity which does not have access.

Go to the application pool and change the identity to your account. Here is an image for your reference:[image]

Comment: Thank you! Applicaiton Pool Identiy is the issue.